# Difficulty with proving tautologies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have to prove a couple tautologies for a discrete math assignment but I'm stuck.

I've gotten this far:

$$\begin{align}& (x \to y) \wedge (x \to \neg y) \to \neg x
\\ = ~& (\neg x \vee y) \wedge ( x \to \neg y) \to \neg x &&
\tag{translate $\to$} 
\\
=~&(\neg x \vee y) \wedge ( \neg x \vee \neg y) \to \neg x \tag{translate $\to$}\end{align}$$

..and I'm not sure where to go next. I think I have to use the distributive property to rearrange the problem, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Help?

Comment: Distribution!   $\large(a\lor b)\land(a\lor c)~=~a\lor (b\land c)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've gotten this far: (ed: I've added the red brackets to show the implicit order of operations.)
>
> $$\begin{align}& \color{crimson}((x \to y) \wedge (x \to \neg y)\color{crimson}) ~\to~ \neg x\\ = ~& \color{crimson}((\neg x \vee y) \wedge ( x \to \neg y)\color{crimson}) ~\to~ \neg x \tag{translate $\to$} \\ =~&\color{crimson}((\neg x \vee y) \wedge ( \neg x \vee \neg y)\color{crimson}) ~\to~ \neg x \tag{translate $\to$}\end{align}$$
>
> ..and I'm not sure where to go next. I think I have to use the distributive property to rearrange the problem, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Just distribute out the common disjunct in the antecedent of the conjunction. $$\begin{align}=~&\color{crimson}(\lnot x\lor(y\land\lnot y)\color{crimson})~\to~\lnot x\tag{distribution}\end{align}$$

The rest should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done!

```
~x or (y and ~y) [undistribute]
~x or F [simultaneous conjunctivism]
~x [falsification disappearato]
```